# Mongodb error500 in find method

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

I have a problem with [mongodb](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html)...

All works fine in local, but when I put all to the server, I have a error 500 when I do this:

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
$conversation = $dm->getRepository('AppBundle:MessageUser')->findAll();
```

> Error 500 on 2nd line -> $conversation

(I tried without the `->getManager()`, that works on local but not in server)

Here is my **config.yml** :

```
doctrine_mongodb:
connections:
    default:
        server: "%mongodb_server%"
        options: {}
default_database: Database
document_managers:
    default:
        auto_mapping: true
```

And

```
mongodb_server: mongodb://localhost:27017
```

I think I have the good configurations because when I do this:

> php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:schema:update
>   php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents AppBundle

I have 0 errors on both commands.

But when I go on the server and try to see the collections of the server, I don't see the `MessageUser` class (with show dbs, use, show collections...).

For me, I have a problem with the database path, but not sure so where can I set the "path" for the mongo database.

Comment: Can you show us the full stack-trace ?

Comment: I am using Postman for test the request but postman give me 0 logs ...

Comment: You want logs right ? or more detail code ?